# How to check if a layer is in the user's view: openlayers

Tags: javascript, html, maps, openlayers, tiles

I have features that need to appear only if they are in the user's field of view, how can I do that [Image of a polygon that needs to be removed if it is off-screen of the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRlMp.png)?

Comment: Do you mean they should only appear on an inner part of the view such as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/view-padding.html ?

Comment: It would look something like this: suppose a circle that should appear only as long as the user "can see" on the map, which can disappear completely while not in the field of view of the device screen

Comment: See my photo that exemplify my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a feature is in the viewport

```
var visibleExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent();

if (feature.getGeometry().intersectsExtent(visibleExtent)) {
  // feature is visible to user
}
```

Note that if the view is rotated there may be some false positives.  They could be eliminated by testing the rotated geometry and extent as in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Comment: That's what it was! Thank you very much!